# Is there any annotation that affects setter behaviour in C# or formatting the textbox content on form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, annotations

I have a property:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z]+\s*,\s*)*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid format")]
public string Names { get; set; }
```

Annotation enables the user to write strings in the textbox(multiple razor views) like:

```
ala, ela,    ola   , tola                          ,  wiola
```

and they will match the regular expression. I want to give user such freedom, but at the same time I want to get rid all of the whitespace characters when assigning to the `Names` property, so the next time I present the `Names` to the user they will be presented in a readable way, I also want to store them in civilised way in XML without all the whitespaces.

**Possible solution** that I don't like: of course I can create private field and remove all the whitespaces in the setter of the property before assigning, but to keep consistency in the code style I would like to avoid that.

**Question:** I would like to know is there any way to do it by annotation -> tell that all the whitespaces should be removed when assigning to `Names` property.

Alternatively maybe there is annotation that causes contents of

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Names)
```

to be formatted on form submission?

**Clarification**: I know that I can create more restrictive regex, but that is not what I want as I want to be lenient towards the user's input.

Comment: The following regex will only allow single spaces between words - `^(\w+\s?)*$`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I simplified the real regex I use there, but thanks.I want to allow user what I am allowing at this moment, but I want to process it before assigning to the property by removing all the whitespaces and the question is to inquire if I can do it through a annotation rather than processing in the setter..

Comment: Not clear why you want to allow the user to input multiple spaces, but then remove them - why allow it in the first place? (and no, annotations cannot alter data - you need to write your own code do do that)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Becuase user can copy some "names" ( ; ) ) from a source I didn't predicted and I don't want to force the user to check for few minutes if he ommitted something or inserted a space by mistake at char number 124124124 if I can do it for the user.